# Naming Python scratch files during creation in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, scratch-file

Is it possible to get Pycharm to prompt for a scratch file name when making a new scratch file as opposed to having to rename the file after it's been made? This is purely for a smoother workflow experience and/or organization of my scratch files.

Alternatively is there a keyboard shortcut to Refactor>Rename the current file?